# Issues tokenizing text

Tags: text, mining

Started text analysing, and eventually ran into a need for downloading Corpora in using PyCharm2019 as IDE. Not really sure what traceback message wants me to do, since I used PyCharm's own lib import interface to enable Corpora already. Why does an error stating that Corpora is not available to the code keep reappearing?

Imported TextBlob, tried to do a line like: from textblob import TextBlob...view code below

```
from textblob import TextBlob

TextBlob(train['tweet'][1]).words

print("\nPRINT TOKENIZATION") # own instruction to allow for knowing what code result delivers

print(TextBlob(train['tweet'][1]).words)
```

….

Tried to install via nltk, no luck...error when downloading 'brown.tei'

showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1796, in _download
    return self._download_threaded(*e)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 2082, in _download_threaded
    assert self._download_msg_queue == []
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 35, in decorated
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\tokenizers.py", line 57, in tokenize
    return nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize__init__.py", line 104, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 870, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)

---

Resource   File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 995, in *open
punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
    return find(path*, path + ['']).open()

File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 701, in find

> > > import nltk
> > >       nltk.download('punkt')

For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

Searched in:
    - 'C:\Users\jcst/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\share\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\nltk_data'
    - ''

---

```
raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
```

LookupError:

---

Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

> > > import nltk
> > >       nltk.download('punkt')

For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle

Searched in:
    - 'C:\Users\jcst/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\share\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\Users\jcst\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\nltk_data'
    - ''

---

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jcst/PycharmProjects/TextMining/ModuleImportAndTrainFileIntro.py", line 151, in 
    TextBlob(train['tweet'][1]).words
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 24, in **get**
    value = obj.**dict**[self.func.**name**] = self.func(obj)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 649, in words
    return WordList(word_tokenize(self.raw, include_punc=False))
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\tokenizers.py", line 73, in word_tokenize
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(text))
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\base.py", line 64, in itokenize
    return (t for t in self.tokenize(text, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 38, in decorated
    raise MissingCorpusError()
textblob.exceptions.MissingCorpusError: 
Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data: http://nltk.org/data.html
If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.